# Async AJAX call not working with when and then

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code:

```
function accessControl(userId) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "userwidgets",
        type: "get",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            userid: userId
        }
    });
};

var userWidgets = accessControl('1');
$.when(userWidgets).then(function (data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

I don't want to make the function sync by adding the parameter `async: false`, but the alert isn't appearing at all, is there something wrong in my code? should I use another approach?

Comment: what is `totalHours`?

Comment: Where is defined `totalHours`?

Comment: This was by mistake, still same issue though

Comment: Why are you not using `done`? My guess is the Ajax call is failing.

Comment: add a rejection callback argument to `then`. If request fails the first `then` argument won't fire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.ajax` returns a promise. So, it don't need to be wrapped in `$.when` again.

Use `then` directly on `userWidgets` as it is `ajax` instance.

```
userWidgets.then(function (data) {
    alert(data);
}, function(e, status, error) {
    console.log(error);
    // For debugging
});
```

From jQuery [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> **jqXHR.then(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {}, function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {});**
>
> Incorporates the functionality of the `.done()` and `.fail()` methods, allowing (as of jQuery 1.8) the underlying Promise to be manipulated. Refer to `deferred.then()` for implementation details.

Comment: add the second callback of `then`. If request fails alert still won't fire which is likely why OP not seeing it either

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want to make the function sync by adding the parameter async: false, but the alert isn't appearing at all, is there something wrong in my code? should I use another approach?

Making the ajax call synchronous will **not** solve this problem. *Your approach is fine.*

As @Tushar has said in his answer you don't really need to use `$.when` since the `$.ajax`call returns a promise so you can chain `.then` callbacks onto it without using `$.when`. But this is **not** the reason why your `.then` callback is not being invoked.

**The reason why your `.then` callback is not being called** is because that ajax call is failing and the promise is being rejected. `.then` callbacks are only called when promises are resolved successfully, this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AnishPatelUk/a0tcw5hb/) verifies this statement.

You will need add failure logic to your code to handle failures in your ajax call like this:

```
var userWidgets = accessControl('1');
$.when(userWidgets).then(function (data) {
    alert(data);
})
.fail(function(){
   alert("should do something on failure");
});
```